# How do I find a decomposition of a permutation into cycles?

Tags: permutations

I have the follwing question:

> Find the decomposition into cycles with disjoint supports, then determine the order and the signature.

I have the following cycle:

$$\sigma=\left(\begin{array}{rrr} 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\3&4&9&7&6&5&1&2&8\end{array}\right)$$

I remark that $\sigma=\left(\begin{array}{rrr}1&3&9&8&2&4&7\end{array}\right)\cdot \left(\begin{array}{rrr}5&6\end{array}\right)$.
Let us denote $c_1=\left(\begin{array}{rrr}1&3&9&8&2&4&7\end{array}\right)$ and $c_2=\left(\begin{array}{rrr}5&6\end{array}\right)$ We know that $$supp(c_1)=\{5,6\}, supp(c_2)=\{1,2,3,4,8,9\}$$Therefore their intersection is clearly empty. Futhermore $$ord(\sigma)=lcm{(l(c_1),l(c_2))}=lcm(7,2)=14$$ and $$sgn(\sigma)=(-1)^{9-1}=1$$

Does this work like this, the part where I am most unsure is the determination of the support.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What formula are you using to compute the signature? I would have got $(-1)^{7-1}(-1)^{2-1} =-1$.

Comment: Also a comment: you say you have a "cycle" $\sigma$: you don't you have a permutation $\sigma$.

Comment: oh yes I computed it wrong sorry.

Comment: Thank you but could I ask something more. Here we don't have "fixed points" what if we consider $$\sigma =\left(\begin{array}{rrr} 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\2&4&6&8&1&3&5&7&9\end{array}\right)$$ then we would have $$\sigma=(\begin{array}{rrr}1&2&4&8&7&5\end{array})(\begin{array}{rrr}3&6\end{array})$$ But then 9 would be a fixed point, so the support of the first cycle would be $\{3,6,9\}$ and the one of the second cycle would be $\{1,2,4,5,7,8,9\}$ and then the one of the last one would be $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$ right? so we can't use this decomposition?

Comment: You are writing down the complements of the supports instead of the supports! In this case $\sigma=(1 2 4 8 7 5)(3 6)(9)$ of order $6$, supports/orbits $\{1,2,4,7,8,5\},\{3,6\},\{9\}$ and signature $(-1)^{6-1}(-1)^{2-1}(-1)^{1-1}=+1$.

Comment: I see that I missed the mistake before: sorry. Your supports in the original question are swapped.

Comment: So but then I also did it wrong in the previous exercise, i.e. I swaped the definition there

Comment: Do I need to write (9) at the end of my decomposition?

Comment: For the signature: note that it's a homomorphism (respects multiplication) and the signature of a cycle of odd length is $+1$ and of a cycle of even length (including transpositions) is $-1$.

Comment: About $(9)$: it is traditional to omit $1$-cycles, but it is safer (especially if counting things) to leave them in. On reflection $\{9\}$ is an orbit, but is not part of the support.